# Unique index on view with nullable columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6

The view I have correctly returns unique results, but because of the way the view is setup (Id field is from my EmployeeId table) Entity framework tries to cache the results and doesn't read each field (and thus errors because it thinks it finds duplicate keys)

I have the following tables (simplified here):

```
Employee
   Id
   Name

Jobs
  Id
  Name

EmployeeJobAssociations
  Id
  EmployeeId
  JobId
  StartDate
  EndDate

EmployeeJobsView
  Id (This is actually EmployeeId)
  AssociationId (This is EmployeeJobs's Id)
  JobId (Job's table Id)
  Name (EmployeeName)
  JobName
  StartDate
  EndDate
```

The view code is as follows:

```
SELECT        dbo.Employees.Id, dbo.EmployeeJobAssociations.Id AS AssociationId, 
              dbo.Jobs.Id as JobId, dbo.Employees.Name,  dbo.EmployeeJobAssociations.StartDate, 
              dbo.EmployeeJobAssociations.EndDate, Job.Name AS JobName
FROM          dbo.Jobs AS Job INNER JOIN
              dbo.EmployeeJobAssociations ON Job.Id = dbo.EmployeeJobAssociations.JobId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.Employees ON dbo.EmployeeJobAssociations.EmployeeId = dbo.Employees.Id
```

So because I'm using EmployeeId as the primary field (I want employee's who don't have a JobAssociation to show up in my view as well) Entity framework thinks that all results for an employee are the same:

```
Id      AssociationId        JobId    ...        StartDate
1234      1                      1               10/10/10
1234      2                      2               11/11/10 // Unless I turn off tracking it thinks this is the same as the first row
2222      null                null               null
```

Is it possible to make the table have an index based on the EmployeeId (Id) and AssociationId even though AssociationId could be nullable (but only nullable **ONCE** per EmployeeId)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this work around for now:

Setting the AssociationId equal to 0 if its null and then creating a primary key off the EmployeeId and AssociationId

```
ISNULL(dbo.EmployeeJobAssociations.Id, 0) AS AssociationId
```

and in entity framework:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeJobAssociationView>.HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.AssociationId});
```